# When is a molecule with fluorine considered more acidic than one with chlorine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I am learning about acids and bases.  Here is the problem I am stuck on:
[image]

According to organic chemistry as a second language the molecule to the right with fluorine is more acidic than the molecule with chlorine.  I would think that since chlorine is bigger it is more stable resulting in a more stable conjugate base?

Comment: You are thinking along the right lines, but remember that F is also more electron withdrawing than Cl. So how would that effect the stability of the conjugate base anion?

Comment: Chlorine isn't big enough to reduce basicity of conjugate base via steric hindrance.

Comment: @airhuff So would F have a greater electron density, and giving a more negative partial charge? I don't know how that impacts stability?

Comment: @Mithoron can you explain what that means? what is considered "big enough"? and I will look into what you mean by steric hindrance (haven't covered how reactions occur yet).

Comment: The conjugate base has a negative charge on the oxygen. This is what makes the conjugate base basic, and the more electron density you have at that negative charge, the more strongly it will attract a proton to stabilize itself (meaning it's more strongly basic). The fluorine molecules are strongly electron withdrawing, so they can pull some of the electron density away from the negatively charged oxygen, thus partially stabilizing it and reducing the strength with which it attracts protons, making it less basic (more stable).

Comment: That means that Cl atoms aren't big enough to block access to oxygen.